# Кастомное поле WooCommerce не дает ввести пустое значение или ноль

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Я добавил кастомное поле для указание абонентской платы там, где это необходимо. По умолчанию поле пустое. Но стоит в него хоть раз что-то ввести и больше не получается его опустошить или ввести ноль. Каждый раз после обновления в админке в поле появляется предыдущее значение.

Добавлял так:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'art_woo_add_custom_fields' );

function art_woo_add_custom_fields() {
global $product, $post;
echo '<div class="options_group">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
    'id'                => '_text_field',
    'label'             => __( 'Абонентская плата в месяц', 'woocommerce' ),
    'placeholder'       => 'Не заполняйте, если нет',
    'desc_tip'          => 'true',
    'custom_attributes' => array(),
    'description'       => __( 'Абонентская плата в месяц',
    'woocommerce' ),
) );
echo '</div>';
}

/* Сохраняем значение Абонентской платы в базе данных */
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'art_woo_custom_fields_save', 10 );

function art_woo_custom_fields_save( $post_id ) {

$woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_text_field'];
if ( $woocommerce_text_field ) {
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );
}
}

/* Выводим аренду в карточке товара */

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'art_get_text_field_before_add_card' );
function art_get_text_field_before_add_card() {
global $post, $product; }
function filter_woocommerce_get_price_html( $price, $_this ) {
global $post, $product;
$text_field     = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );
        ob_start();
    if ( $text_field ) {
        ?>
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" style="text-transform: none;">
                <span>Абон. плата (месяц): ₽</span>
            <?php echo $text_field; ?>
            </span>
        <?php
    }
    $text = ob_get_clean();
    return  '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" style="text-transform: none;">Подключение: </span>' . $price . ' <br/> ' . $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_get_price_html', 10, 2 );
```

Где ошибся?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции function `art_woo_custom_fields_save` нужно заменить проверку на `isset`:

```
function art_woo_custom_fields_save( $post_id ) {
    $woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_text_field'];
    if ( isset( $woocommerce_text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );
    }
}
```